# Why is reassignment of pandas DataFrame not triggering SettingWithCopyWarning?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

This code works fine:

```
x = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0], [0, 1]])
x = x[x[0] > 0]
x.loc[0, 0] = 2
```

But this code gives `SettingWithCopyWarning`:

```
x = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0], [0, 1]])
y = x[x[0] > 0]
y.loc[0, 0] = 2
```

This is quite confusing. Since python does not support assignment operator override, how does pandas know the difference between `x` and `y`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first snippet you overwrite `x` so there is no copy or reference, for the second you assign to `y` a reference so now a warning is raised because you now have the original df `x` and a reference `y`.

If you want a distinct copy do

```
y = x[x[0]>0].copy()
```

which will not raise a warning as this performs a deep [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html#pandas.DataFrame.copy)

Comment: Thanks! Just out of curiosity, is it reference counting that helps pandas to distinguish the two cases?